# MvxCachingFragmentStatePagerAdapter and app Backgrounding results in a null ViewModel

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

**Steps to reproduce**

Using the sample at GitHub MvvmCross-Samples/XPlatformMenus/

Deploy the app to an Android device with Limit Background Processes set to 1 at the most

Run up the App, select the View Pager example from the menu

Send the app to the background, load a different app, then go back into it again to ensure it has been backgrounded

**Expected behavior**

I would expect that the View Pager fragment would re-appear on the Tab that was selected prior to backgrounding

**Actual behavior**

There is a null reference error returned due to the following code in RecyclerViewFragment.OnCreateView:

```
_itemSelectedToken = ViewModel.WeakSubscribe(() => ViewModel.SelectedItem,
(sender, args) =>
{
    if (ViewModel.SelectedItem != null)
        Toast.MakeText(Activity,
        string.Format("Selected: {0}", ViewModel.SelectedItem.Title),
        ToastLength.Short).Show();
});
```

**The issue is that the ViewModel has not been restored and is null.**

The reason I came across this issue is that i am using the MvxCachingFragmentStatePagerAdapter in my own application but rather than initialising the FragmentInfo with the Type of ViewModel:

```
new MvxCachingFragmentStatePagerAdapter.FragmentInfo("RecyclerView 1", typeof(RecyclerViewFragment), typeof(RecyclerViewModel))
```

I am using the same model for each FragmentInfo:

```
new MvxCachingFragmentStatePagerAdapter.FragmentInfo("RecyclerView 1", typeof(RecyclerViewFragment), ViewModel)
```

This results in the same behaviour - a null ViewModel upon app restore from backgrounding

I'm using MvvmCross 4.4 and Android 7.0